# How to secure data transfer between Rails App on Heroku and a remote IIS Server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, security, windows-server-2008

I'm running a Rails app on Heroku's Cedar stack.
I need to access a remote Windows Server (over the internet, not in a LAN) to query a SQL Server database.

First, I used TinyTDS to access the DB but configuring it on Heroku is really painful.
Secondly, I had made a dynamic web page on the IIS remote server and I was making http get requests to retrieve data. But it's not secure.

I need a good and secure solution (ssh tunnel?).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with using HTTP requests to interface between the two. If you want encryption, just use HTTPS. If it's just for internal use then you don't need to buy an SSL certificate, you can generate one yourself.

Comment: generate one myself... sounds great (but how?). I'm accessing the remote windows server with an IP address. Does I need a domain name mapped to the server?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not actually sure whether or not you can use SSL without a domain name, but it's worth a try. A guide on the microsoft site about generating a self-signed certificate is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127(v=ws.10).aspx), and a guide on doing this with openssl on a *nix host [here](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html). I'm not familiar with IIS but you will need to configure it such that the certificate is only used for the database API page.

Comment: Also note that, whilst this does prevent eavesdropping of communications, it won't stop someone else from making requests to that server. Make sure to have some sort of random, secret value which is sent along with every request, and have the IIS page check it's correct before doing anything with the DB.

Comment: Okay, thank you for answering and for the links. I'll investigate this and get back to you later. I'll mark your answered as accepted as soon as I've implemented your solution.

Comment: Hi. Not yet... simple http requests for now :-/